# convert counter list in python of nltk bigraph

Tags: python, list, nltk, counter

I want to convert the output of my list. I used **nltk** to find bigraphs from tokens.

This is the output I got after counter:

```
[(('declaration', 'rights'), 8), (('rights', 'freedoms'), 8), (('peoples', 'nations'), 3)]
```

Desired output:

```
['declaration rights', 'rights freedoms', 'peoples nations']
```

Is there a fix for this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `list comprehension` and `join` to combine first element of bigram results:

```
output_bigrams = [(('declaration', 'rights'), 8), (('rights', 'freedoms'), 8), (('peoples', 'nations'), 3)]
print(output_bigrams)
```

Result:

```
[(('declaration', 'rights'), 8), (('rights', 'freedoms'), 8), (('peoples', 'nations'), 3)]
```

Then, using `list comprehension` and `join` to combine first element of results:

```
result = [' '.join(element[0]) for element in output_bigrams]
print(result)
```

Result:

```
['declaration rights', 'rights freedoms', 'peoples nations']
```